# run actions in SceneKit Editor

Tags: ios, action, scenekit

I added a rotate around axis action into SceneKit Editor. I would like to see what the action looks like by clicking Run command at the bottom of the SceneKit Editor. However, every time I run the action, the object rotating just gets blurred. I know that this is not what I programmed because I can see frame by frame simulation as indicated in the video. Is this a bug or should I run actions differently. Thanks for help.

VIDEO SHOWING THE PROBLEM: https://vid.me/cUwZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you see is the view jittering even though actions are running – that's a bug in SceneKit. As a workaround you can temporarily add a particle system or physics body in your scene to prevent the view from jittering.

Comment: wow interesting. Just curious, how did you come up with the workaround?